# Test settings contains additional files to be deployed but the copy order is not clear

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I [have](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11565/how-to-configure-tfs-test-plan-to-run-automated-ui-tests-against-different-envir) a related question to this case.

The original issue is about how to modify the test settings in order to run tests against different test environments from the same agent machine. The config values (username, db access, etc.) are stored in web.config (during build it will be project.name.dll.config) belongs to the project.

I got the suggestion to create test settings for every test environment I have and attach a poject.name.dll.config file for each which contains the proper environment settings as a file to be deployed. You can find this option in Test Manager - Particular test plan - Run settings - Advanced - Deployment.

I put together my configs accordingly but, it seems, the attached file copy before the compiled project because the settings defined in the web.config (it will be renamed to project.name.dll.config) will be applied.

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475(v=vs.110).aspx) page describes the order of the copy but it doesn't mention clearly when the additional files will be copied.

How can I solve this issue? Do you have any other workaround for my issue? Do you know any blog post about it?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That is the wrong way to achieve the result. Using testsettings to deploy variables to environments is not its intended purpose.

You should use Release Management for Visual Studio to manage the variables and let you deploy the same bits to different servers with different config settings.

http://nakedalm.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

I have linked to an example of how to do this with the latest bits, and it all works with TFS 2012.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems really pro stuff, but in my case it is not useful. 
Our test code is in different solution than the products. So, deploying it is not necessary. On the other hand, just for overwrite a part of the web.config file utilizing RM, for me, it is a little bit too much.